# Expo: Set default development server

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

When I start my Expo server and run the app on emulator/simulator, I want to use `localhost`by default without opening the server selection screen of the Expo.

[image: expo development server selection screen]

Why do I need this?

I want to test a deeplink by pressing the link in Notes app while the app is closed. My app is getting stuck on splash screen when opened by deeplink.

I have looked at the Expo documents related to starting the server and running the app on local with a debug build. But I haven't seen an option/configuration to skip the Expo server selections creen.

Comment: Are you using EAS to build the app? Are you using Expo with `expo-dev-client? With this information, I will be able to assist you.